# Publishing Facebook (v2.3) comment on friends post from Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After a few days of frustration, I would kindly ask for your help [also apologies as I am very new to FB]. I have an Android app in development, it has a Facebook app id, keys, hashes, etc. I created 4 test users for (obviously) test purposes and made all of these friends and users of the app. The app is set for v2.3 API. I see the increasing restrictions that Facebook is imposing, but I still think that I can do what I need to do ...

On login on the mobile, after the 'two-step' login with simple permission and then ask for more, I ultimately have these permissions:

```
user_friends
user_posts
manage_pages
publish_pages
publish_actions
public_profile
```

For a (test) user of the app, that has not yet logged into the app and has therefore not yet granted any permissions, when I query

```
/v2.3/{user-id}/feed    or     /v2.3/{user-id}/posts
```

I get a "200" (non-error) JSON response with no data, from memory its something like this:

```
{
  "data" : [
  ]
}
```

which agrees with the documentation as given in [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed)
where it says:

> If you attempt to read data from a feed that your app has not been authorized to access, the call will return an empty array. OK, so all that makes sense.

So then I get a list of messages from a friend (test user at this point) and store their message ids, it looks like they are in the form: userid_postid and I can scan the text, great. I use API v2.3 which looks like it will close in July 2017, but it works now.

OK, so now I want to post to the users wall or page or something that FB calls it - is it true that I can't do this anymore? I next tried to post to the comments of the stored user_postid but this fails with:

```
{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}
```

I do think I should have the permission to do this. I do notice that there is no comment widget on the test users posts - is that the problem? Do some posts not have comments at all, or is this a function of test users only? Here is what the posts look like, note there is no comment line shown:

[image: There is no comment line like I have on my page???]

I've come a long way, and can do quite a bit (get posts, user pics, friends that use the app - despite FB's documentation) but am now stuck. Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

EDIT, forgot the code for the attempted publish to a comment:

```
        params.putString("message", someText);              
        new GraphRequest(
                // version 2.3 will work until July 8, 2017
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/v2.3/" + mFacebookPostId + "/comments",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        mSends++;
                        FacebookRequestError err = response.getError();
                        if (err == null || err.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                            mSendGood++;
                        }
                        tv_status.setText("Sent " + mSends + " posts, " + mSendGood + " good");
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Update: am I supposed to get a 'page access token', again the FB docs are not clear?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be a [bug with the Facebook Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/678253368976671/). I was never sure if I could do what I wanted to do as this was a first FB development for me, but started to get suspicious when I saw that Test User's posts do not have comments or like buttons.

But now I am not sure how to test this code, as real users can't use the app in development mode?